Trying in PowerAutomate to get a snippet from Gmail gives error
In a flow
Trigger: When a new gmail arrives
Get email details: There is an error - also raw outputs
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>

With a status code: 400

Please can anybody help with this problem.
I am trying to
Trigger: when Gmail arrives, from specific contact, and with specific subject line
Test constraint: Mail snippet contains either one word or a another.
If word A do this, if word B do this...
